# Returning the whole document when matching one field of an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like such:

```js
db.collection1 = 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId(),
    "array" : [
        {
            "userid" : ObjectId(),
            "subfield1" : string,
            "subfield2" : number,
            "subfield3" : number,
            "subfield4" : Date
        },...
    ],
    "field1" : date,
    "field2" : date,
    "field3" : date,
    "field4" : date,
    "field5" : number,
    "field6" : [],
    "field7" : String,
    "field8" : {}
},...
```

Now, I am using a find query on the basis of the userid field inside the array, that is somewhat like this:

```js
db.collection1.find({array:{"$elemMatch":{userid:uId}})
```

But what I also want is just before retrieving a record it should fetch that particular array element also and append it as a property of the returned object.

My 2nd query for this would be:

```js
db.collection1.find({'array.userId':uId},{'array.$':1})
```

But I want the result of this 2nd query to be appended as a propery of the object returned in first query

I hope I am clear.....

OK

My projection would be something like this:

```js
{array.subfield2:0,array.subfield3:0,field2:0,field6:0,field7:0}
```

So this is what I want as a result...suppposing there are 3 users and the third user matches the userId that I am passing. The retrieved document should look like this.

```js
{
 _id: ObjectId(),
 array:[
 {
  userid:ObjectId(1),
  subfield1:string,
  subfield4:Date
 },
 {
  userid:ObjectId(2),
  subfield1:string,
  subfield4:Date
 },
 {
  userid:ObjectId(3),
  subfield1:string,
  subfield4:Date
 }],
 "field1" : date,
 "field3" : date,
 "field4" : date,
 "field5" : number,
 "field8" : {},
 DynamicField://This is the userobj of the 3rd usr which matches. Whole & intact 
 {
   "userid" : ObjectId(3),
   "subfield1" : string,
   "subfield2" : number,
   "subfield3" : number,
   "subfield4" : Date
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a lot of people have been confused by your terminology of "appending", but if I read between the lines of what you are saying you seem to want the "whole document" to be returned but only including the "matched element" of the array.

So like all general "field selection" techniques, you have to be very specific with MongoDB and include **all** of the field names in your projection:

```js
db.collection1.find(
    { "array.userid": uId },   // Don't need elemMatch with one field
    {
        "array.$": 1,
        "field1": 1,
        "field2": 1,
        "field3": 1,
        "field4": 1,
        "field5": 1,
        "field6": 1,
        "field7": 1,
        "field8": 1,
    }
)
```

The `_id` is always included unless explicitly excluded and you cannot "mix" other includes/excludes in here, not that it would make much sense since you need the matched position within the array.

**Edit:**  I have no idea why you would want to do this, to me the above form is much better:

```js
 db.collection1.aggregate([
     // Filter the matching document, as you do not want to do the rest of the
     // steps over the whole collection
     { "$match": {
         "array.userid": uId,   // Don't need elemMatch with one field
     }},

     // Store the original document, and a copy of the array
     { "$project": {
         "array": 1,
         "field1": 1,
         "field3": 1,
         "field4": 1,
         "field5": 1,
         "field8": 1,
         "dynamicField": "$array"
     }},

     // Unwind the array
     { "$unwind": "$dynamicField" },

     // Just match the field you want
     { "$match": { "dynamicField.userid": uId } },

     // Play with the other array now
     { "$unwind": "$array" },

     // Change the projection
     { "$project": {
         "array.userId": "$array.userId",
         "array.subfield1": "$array.subfield1", 
         "array.subfield4": "$array.subfield4", 
         "field1": 1,
         "field2": 1,
         "field3": 1,
         "field4": 1,
         "field5": 1,
         "field6": 1,
         "field7": 1,
         "field8": 1,
         "dynamicField": 1
     }},

     // Group back the array
     { "$group": {
         "_id": "$_id",
         "array": { "$push": "$array" },
         "field1": { "$first": "$field1" },
         "field3": { "$first": "$field3" },
         "field4": { "$first": "$field4" },
         "field5": { "$first": "$field5" },
         "field8": { "$first": "$field8" },
         "dynamicField": { "$first": "$dynamicField" }
     }}

 ])
```

Comment: Actually, yes I think I have not made it clear enough. So, I would like to state my intentions again. The array, in the above case, is a list of user objects. Now I want to retrieve the whole documents. Since I am using projections, in the array also, I won't get all the properties inside it. But one particular array entry in which the user Id matches, that specific array record I want seperately and as a whole devoid of any projections.

Comment: @AnkitMurarka You're right, that is very unclear. Nothing like your original title at all, and more or less the reverse of what is there now. So you just want **one** field from the array right? Which field? You do not say this anywhere. The `userId` maybe?

Comment: Just check the edit that I have made in the question. i have also tried to give an example of the retrieved document that I would want. Hope it would be clear now. Sorry for the ambiguity in the question. Maybe I am not using the right keywords. Sorry for that.

Comment: @AnkitMurarka You use case baffles me, but I have included the way to do this with the aggregation framework.

Comment: Thanks a ton. That definitely worked like a charm. But later on I figured out I dont need the last $group condition and the $unwind condition for the array field. As, without doing so the result is also achieved. So, I would like to ask why you are actually unwinding the array field and then grouping it back. Thanks a ton though. Really got me out of a sticky situation

Comment: The reason why I want to do so is, see, each record is having the user array. It is an array of user objects involved in that record. Now just before retrieving I want to also get the user who is retrieving that record by matching the uId. That is the primary user in this case. That is the only way of identifying the user who is retrieving the record.

Comment: @AnkitMurarka Simply put, you asked to alter the fields in the "array" element to only contain certain fields (subfield1, subfield4, userId), so that is how you manipulate that. To your last comment, for myself, I would have just done an unwind and projected an additional "selected" field on the matching array entry to suit the purpose you seem to be describing. Overall less work to do, but I'll leave that as an exercise for you to try out.

Comment: I didn't quiet get what you were trying to achieve. Maybe what you understood and what I was trying to explain were 2 different scenarios. So, I guess let it be, I was able to perfectly achieve the result that I wanted with the help of your answer and in the process I also learnt some important concepts of mongoDb, so thanks for that.